# @ViewScope vs @RequestScope file download

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I am using:

- JSF: 2.2.13
- Primefaces: 6.2

**PROBLEM**: When I make "ImageView" bean @ViewScoped then my file downloads after pressing the button. When I make "ImageView" bean @RequestScoped then my file doesn't download and the app simply opens a new page (the current page) without any URL params (so just opens http://localhost:8080/imageView.jsf)

SUSPECTED PROBLEM: Maybe <f:param> sends diffrent things depending if the ImageView is @ViewScoped vs @RequestScope

I open the page with the following GET REQUEST http://localhost:8080/imageView.jsf?contentFileId=1

I have the following code:

```
<h:form id="form">
    <p:commandButton id="btn" value="Download"
                        icon="fa fa-download" ajax="false">
        <f:param name="contentFileId" value="#{imageView.contentFileId}" />
        <p:fileDownload value="#{streamedContentView.image}"/>
    </p:commandButton>
</h:form>
```

The beans:

1. ImageView

```
@Named
@RequestScoped
public class ImageView implements Serializable {
    private String contentFileId;

    @PostConstruct
    private void init() {
        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) FacesContext
            .getCurrentInstance()
            .getExternalContext()
            .getRequest();

        contentFileId = request.getParameter("contentFileId");

    }
    //...GETTERS & SETTERS
}
```

2. StreamedContentView

```
@Named
@ApplicationScoped
public class StreamedContentView {

    @Inject
    ContentFileManager contentFileManager;

    public StreamedContent getImage() throws URISyntaxException, IOException {
        //Get id of file
        FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        Map<String, String> requestParameterMap = context.getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap();
        String rawContentFileId = requestParameterMap.get("contentFileId");

        //Get file
        ContentFile contentFile = contentFileManager.findById(Long.parseLong(rawContentFileId));
        InputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(contentFile.getContents());
        return new DefaultStreamedContent(stream, contentFile.getMimeType(), contentFile.getFileName());
        
    }
}
```

Comment: What version of PrimeFaces and JSF are you using?

Comment: JSF : 2.2.13

Primefaces version: 6.2